# problema con pasar ciertos datos de un pdf a un xml a python

Tags: python, xml

quiero los datos de ciertas coordenadas de un pdf y para pasar a un xml y para eso use la libreria que ofrece python para la conversion de pdf a xml pero necesito unos datos especificos del pdf para pasarlo por ejemplo el monto, pero no me funciona y tampoco ayuda chatGPT

espero poder tener el programa que pase los datos de ciertas coordenadas del pdf al xml el cual es el monto de algo